# empty request.FILES in django when upload image from android

Tags: android, python, django, image, upload

I want to upload image from android app to djnago. this is my android code to upload image:

```
public void upload(String filepath) throws IOException{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SoberRequest.UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL);
     File file = new File(filepath);
     MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
     builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
     FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
     builder.addPart("image", cbFile);
     HttpEntity mpEntity = builder.build();
     httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
     httppost.setHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     ...
}
```

and this is my django code to get and save image:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_image(request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            destination_path = open("Images/filan.jpg", "wb+")
            print(request.FILES)
            image = request.FILES['image']
            destination_path.write(image)
            destination_path.close()
            json_data = {"status": SUCCESSFUL}
             return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_data), mimetype=json_mimeType)
        else:
            json_data = {"status": ERROR}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_data), mimetype=json_mimeType)
```

when i print request.FILES, it is empty : . and django raise this MultiValueDictKeyError exeption. what is problem? thanks

Comment: Which version of django do you use?

Comment: 1) Try to check your request.POST dict and sure that there is no any variable like `cbFile` or something like this.
2) Try to update django. There was some bugs with MultiValueDictKeyError in older versions.
3) Try to debug in on android side. Does it send correct data to server?